# Native Javascript - Has attribute else if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, vanilla-forums

I've setup my variables and name it like this :

```
const x = document.querySelector(".ui-datepicker-trigger");
const y = document.querySelector("#ctl00_c_TransPwdFunc_img100");
```

Once i setup the variables I was creating the if statement and the code is below:

```
if (x.hasAttribute("src", "/mvptest_int/App_themes/btnCalendar.png") == x){
            x.setAttribute("src","/mvptest_int/App_themes/btnCalendarWhite.png");
            console.log(x);
        } else if (y.hasAttribute("src", "../App_Themes/btnGetSMS.png" == y)){
            y.setAttribute("src","../App_Themes/btnGetSMSWhite.png");
        }
```

I have tested this out inside the console log individually and they are both working. But the issues that i'm facing is that:

x attribute is only showing up in the beginning and once a users click next it will disappear and this is the issue what i'm facing:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzKRu.png) [Code error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzqlM.png)

So i can see my x changes is working correctly but none of my java script are working because of this error message.

Could someone please help me with this issue and also let me know if there a better solution to do this.

Thanks

FE Look:
[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvKqk.png)
[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssk4a.png)

Comment: `.hasAttribute` returns either `true` or `false`, which cannot be equal to `x`, a `Node`, except if `x` is `null` (in which case `.hasAttribute` will raise an error); meanwhile `y`, also a `Node` (or `null`) cannot ever be equal to a non-empty string. Without knowing the intent and the context of this code, we can't tell you more than "it doesn't make sense".

Comment: Looks like your `y` selector is failing, but without the HTML, hard to say why

Comment: Thank you for the advise @Amadan 

What i'm trying to achieve is this :

if(this x attribute is found on the first page change the attribute value to the new one) else if (this y attribute is found on the first page change the attribute value to the new one) if (nothing is found skip this code )

x and y attribute sits in two different pages.

What would be the best way to write this??

Comment: What is "first page"? And `x` and `y` aren't attributes in your code, they are element nodes.

Comment: noted thanks for the input, i will remember that :) Sorry I am still new into this and trying to learn everything.

I've just added couple more screenshot and explain the issue i'm having with my script:
1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvKqk.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssk4a.png

Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute), you can see that the `element.hasAttribute` return `true` or `false` and require only one attribute, not as you did.
That why you have the error.

And supposed that you use the `x.hasAttribute("src") == x`, it will never return true.

Last point, make sure that your `x` element exists.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is this :

if(this x attribute is found on the first page change the attribute value to the new one) else if (this y attribute is found on the first page change the attribute value to the new one) if (nothing is found skip this code )

x and y attribute sits in two different pages.

What would be the best way to write this??

Thanks for your help